# Using multiple proxies across different JCEF browser instances

Tags: java, chromium, chromium-embedded, proxies

This question pertains to JCEF chromium embedded framework and it's ability to use proxies:

Hi, I'm currently creating multiple browser instances and passing a proxy to them using the --proxy-server command line flag and passing that into CefApp.getInstance. However the CefApp is static so that is only one of them meaning that 1st proxy passed in is the proxy that will be used for the all browser instances. In jcefs current form is it possible to use multiple proxies?

Comment: Cross-posted, link for reference: http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=14939